# Associate Task to attachment in inbound email service

Tags: apex-email-service

Hello I have created a Email service to capture customer replies. It is working fine. But I am not able to associate Incoming Email attachments with task. I can associate`` them with contacts but not tasks don't understand why?

```
  task t = new task();
        t.Priority='Normal';
        t.Status='Inbound Email';
        t.Subject=email.subject;
        t.TaskSubtype='Email';
        t.IsReminderSet=true;
        t.ReminderDateTime=System.now()+1;
        t.WhoId=acc.personcontactId;
        t.whatid=acc.id;
        newTask.add(t);
        insert newTask;
        System.debug('New Task Object: ' + acc.name+acc.id);   
        if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
            for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                // attach to the newly created contact record
                attachment.ParentId = t.Id;
                attachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
                attachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
                insert attachment;
            }
        }
        if (email.TextAttachments != null && email.TextAttachments.size() > 0) {
            for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.TextAttachments.size() ; i++) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(); 
                attachment.Name = email.TextAttachments[i].fileName;
                attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(email.TextAttachments[i].body);
                attachment.ParentId = t.Id;
                insert attachment;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You have used 2 if conditions inside which attachments are created? Did you check to see if the code is correctly going into one of these loops?

Comment: @RedDevil yes Code is correclty going into these loops if i use accountid attachment is also getting attached but i want to attach it with task being created

Comment: Did you check logs to see if there is an exception?

Comment: Edit: I got this to work. Attachments are getting added in Files Related list not in Attachment related list. So code is okay. Just add the Files related list in task page layout and you are done

Comment: post that as answer. will help someone in the future